# Generate macOS-like password using terminal and bash

Tags: bash

I want to generate a password that would follow the pattern of passwords Apple prompts during account creation.

A password string pattern will look like this `xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx`. Where one `x` is a number and one `x` is a capital letter. **Hyphens also need to be included.**

The result may look like this: `abcdef-ghijk3-mnoPqr` - where `3` is a number and `P` is a capital letter.

Valid outputs are:

- `abcdef-ghijk1-mnoPqr` (`1` and `P`)
- `abcd3F-ghijkl-mnopqr` (`3` and `F`)
- `abcdef-Ghijkl-mn0pqr` (`G` and `0`)
- `abcdef-nhijk1-mnqrX` (`1` and `X`)

Invalid outputs are:

- `aBCD3f-Nh1jk1-Mn0qr`
- `AbcDwF-gH1jJl-mn0FqR`

How can I do it using typical bash commands `sed` or `awk` and similar?

Comment: `pwgen -Bns 6 3 | tr '\n' -`?

Comment: So you mean 1 number, 1 upper case letter,  and 16 lower case letters?

Comment: Why is this tagged `sh` **and** `bash`? Please focus in one question on one single shell language.

Comment: @user1934428  Yes, 1 number, 1 upper letter, and 16 lower case letters with a hyphen after every 6 signs.

Comment: @Biffen No, please have a look at the edited question. I hope it's more transparent about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner solution which I was looking for will be like this:

```
echo "$(tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 5; tr -dc 'A-Z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 1)-$(tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 5; tr -dc 'A-Z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 1)-$(tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 5; tr -dc 'A-Z0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 1)"
```

Because it's much more complex than I assumed, I also wrote a more readable bash script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

makepasswd() {
    (   chars=$(LC_ALL=C tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 2000 ; echo '')
        tr -cd '0-9' <<<"$chars" | head -c 1
        tr -cd 'A-Z' <<<"$chars" | head -c 1
        tr -cd 'a-z' <<<"$chars" | head -c 16
    ) | sed 's/./&\n/g' \
      | shuf \
      | paste -d'\0' - - - - - - \
      | paste -d'-' - - -
}

for in in {1..5}; do makepasswd; done
```